# ListView - DefaultButton

Tags: asp.net, listview, webforms

I have a ListView which I'm using to generate a table. I have a few cells with textboxes and a button which cuases a postback. If the textboxes were in a Panel, I know I could use the DefaultButton attribute, but if I wrap my  in a panel I'll end up with invalid HTML. Is there any way UI can mimic the DefaultButton behavious in a ListView.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`HtmlForm.DefaultButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton.aspx) property for this:

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = "SubmitButton";
```